# How to show that CM-finite Gorenstein algebras have finite global dimension?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, gorenstein

Let $A$ be a Gorenstein algebra(We call $A$ Gorenstein provided that the regular module $A$ has finite injective dimension on both sides. And if $A$ is Gorenstein, then $inj.dim _AA= inj.dim A_A$ ), $A$-Gproj is the full subcategory of $A$-mod consisting of Gorenstein projective modules.  We call $A$ $d$-Gorenstein if $inj.dim _AA= inj.dim A_A \leq d$. We call $A$ CM-finite provide that up to isomorphism there are only finitely many indecomposable modules in $A$-Gproj.

For each $d \geq 1$, denote by $\Omega^d(A-mod)$ the class of modules of the form $\Omega^d(M)$ for a module $M$. There is an equivalence: the algebra $A$ is $d$-Gorenstein iff $A$-Gproj =$\Omega^d(A-mod)$. Now how to use this equivalence get that Gorenstein algebra $A$ is CM-finite implies the algebra $A$ has finite global dimension?(By the equivalence, we can get $\Omega^d(A-mod)$ is representation-finite, then I don't know what to do next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not true:* For example, take $A=k[x]/(x^n)$. This is a self-injective algebra, so it is $0$-Gorenstein. Therefore, every $A$-module is Gorenstein-projective, and moreover there are only finitely many indecomposable $A$-modules (remember the classification of nilpotent endomorphisms of vector spaces). Nonetheless, $A$ is of infinite global dimension.

Comment: I have seen some papers, they all say that a Gorenstein algebra is CM-finite if and only if it has finite global dimension. For example, http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xwchen/Personal%20Papers/postdoc-Xiao-Wu%20Chen%202010.pdf, on the top of page 26. So where is wrong?

Comment: @Penson I think that in that reference "CM-finite" may be a typo for "CM-free". The claim you mention appears immediately after "CM-free" is defined.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard Oh, yes, you are right. I find in other place that: a Gorenstein algebra is CM-free iff it has finite global dimension. Thank you

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for clarifying!